# Code blocks MinGW and the %n conversion character

Tags: c, mingw, printf, codeblocks

I am trying to use a conversion character to count the number of chars printed so far with the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("%s: %nFoo\n", "hello", &n);
    printf("%*sBar\n", n, "");
}
```

When working correctly this code prints Hello Foo, then on the next line Bar is aligned with Foo.

This works fine when compiled with GCC on my linux box. However, when compiled using minGW in code blocks on my Windows PC %n does not work, and all that is printed is **hello: Bar** all on one line. Why so and can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use compile option `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`

E.g

```
>gcc prog.c -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO
```

or

```
>clang prog.c -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO
```

---

Another solution is placing this command above the first import statement like so (see below). This will ensure that the ANSI I/O standards are preferred over Microsoft's. More information in this link [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/printf%20and%20scanf%20family).

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Can you link a document? I spent a while trying to dig for more details on this one and I am curious what I missed when searching.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/printf%20and%20scanf%20family

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is a Windows issue, this [article](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=87) says:

> The default C-RunTime Library (msvcrt.dll) on Vista seems to have %n disabled by default - security reasons of course

It looks like there is a [_set_printf_count_output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175782.aspx) to enable it.

BLUEPIXY found that in order to get it working outside `Visual Studio` you [need to define](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/printf%20and%20scanf%20family) `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
```

Comment: That's great, but how do I call that command using Code Blocks? I have an undefined reference error. I even tried it in Visual Studio 2010 and got a similar error.

Comment: Not sure, I am able to get the MSDN code to work for visual studio in rextester, [see it live](http://rextester.com/LQB95928).