# not correctly counting the number of characters wrriten so far

Tags: c, codeblocks

as my knowledge, the use of %n = "the associated argument is a pointer to an integer into which the number of characters written so far is placed.
i am using using win 8, codeblocks IDE. I tried a program that should print at least 15 character. but it is showing only 8. I have restarted the program even the computer but the result is same.

i also compiled it from command line.

the fragment of code has given below.

snap shot of result uploaded.

first is out put with out the random number.
[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main(void)
  {
   int i;
   printf("%d %f \n%n",100, 123.23, &i);
   printf("%d characters is so far.",i);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `main()` must return `int`, it's not the cause of your problem, but you must know it.

Comment: It works correctly, BTW you need `stdlib.h` for `rand()`, enable compiler warnings so you can be informed of that.

Comment: Thanks for ur remainder, as  small code and i also thought that it may not problem, for that ignored..@ iharob

Comment: @BlackSwan Show us the true code or true screenshots. Either way, you make fuzz around nothing atm.

Comment: `rand()` returns `int` and hence it's acidentally working, a problem will happen if you use `malloc()`, just use warnings and avoid all the trouble, also, you do know that you need `srand()`, don't you?

Comment: It should print "16 characters is so far" and this is what it does. Check it [here](http://codepad.org/WFc8qJEo)

Comment: @ zubergu..please see..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is specific to Windows and it stems from the fact that Windows' C library disables the `%n` specifier for security reasons.

To bypass this, go to `Settings -> Compiler`, and in `Global Compiler Settings` go to `Other options` and add `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`. This will enable the `%n` specifier.

Comment: Thank u very much. i would like to know how u have solve this? i also be very happy if u give me some resource that can help me to trouble shot codeBlocks.

Comment: @BlackSwan I found it unfortunate how many people were doubting your code and output and downvoting you even though you supplied screenshots, so I installed CodeBlocks on my Windows machine to see if I could replicate the problem (I could - my output was 2 instead of 8). I ran the code in Visual Studio and it wouldn't even run, which led me to discover that Windows disables the `%n` specifier. Some Googling led me to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21201851/3791842). I don't use CodeBlocks so I can't direct you to CodeBlocks resources, sorry.. But Google is your friend!

Comment: @BlackSwan It's not CodeBlock's fault, it's windows c library as explain in this answer, very unexpected for me. Can you explain what where you expecting from `printf("%d\n", rand());`?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>[EDIT :: Added after the question was edited]</sup>

As mentioned in **@Daniel**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28563473/2173917), this looks like a specific problem to your OS Specific C library.  It looks like `%n` format specifier is not being supported.

---

*Still, the below answer is helpful (and IMHO, required), so keepting it as it was.*

I think, you mis-read the definition. It does not count *all* the previous calls, rather, it considers the output from same call *only*.

As per chapter 7.21.6.1, `C11` standard, `fprintf()` description, paragraph 8  [emphasis mine]

> n
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is written the
> number of characters written to the output stream ***so far by this call*** to
> fprintf. No argument is converted, but one is consumed. If the conversion
> specification includes any flags, a field width, or a precision, the behavior is
> undefined.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71086/discussion-on-answer-by-sourav-ghosh-not-correctly-counting-the-number-of-charac).