# Format modifier and percentage symbol issues

Tags: c

1. First question

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       int k;
       printf("hello\n%n", &k);
       printf("k: %d", k);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   The above code executes fine in Linux terminal and yields `k: 6`. When I execute that code on Windows using Code::Blocks, `k` returns a value that looks like a memory address. A sample output using Windows 10:

   ```
   hello\n
   k: 4123991
   ```

   I looked up Code::Blocks 16.01 setting->compiler then in 'compiler flags' tab I could not find any useful check-box button that will fix the problem I describe.

   What am I doing wrong? I want to see `k=6` not `k=4123991` when I execute that code using Windows and Code::Blocks (build->build and run, F9 button).
2. Second question

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       int k = 5;
       printf("%*%\n",k);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   I was expecting to see k-1 spaces followed by a `%` symbol. Sadly, I see a `%` and no leading spaces at all. What am I ignoring?

Comment: With 'When i execute that code on windows using code::blocks ", do you get any compiler warnings with `printf("hello\n%n", &k);`?

Comment: ||warning: command line option '-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C|

Comment: why first code should output 6? I don't see 6 anywhere in your code

Comment: @ Lashane hello\n that is 6 characters, that 6 is saved in k variable :)

Comment: `printf("%*%...` is not defined by the C standard, so on your implementation, it may be UB.

Comment: (2) The POSIX specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), quoting the C standard, says `% Print a '%' character; no argument is converted. The complete conversion specification shall be %%.`

Comment: The first code outputs two values. Please describe what you expect, and what you got in both cases.

Comment: @Mynicks this is not how printf works

Comment: I suspect windows is not letting `printf("%n", ... );` to work as it viewed by some as a security risk.  Likely some option can be enabled to over-ride.

Comment: In the second code you ask "What am i ignoring?" You are ignoring the compiler's warnings.

Comment: [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx): *Because the `%n` format is inherently insecure, it is disabled by default. If `%n` is encountered in a format string, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation. To enable `%n` support, see `_set_printf_count_output`.*

Comment: `printf("%*s\n",5, "%");` will print "5-1 spaces followed by a % symbol"

Comment: @Lashane: this is how `printf()` works according to the C standard.  `printf_s()` doesn't accept `%n` at all, but the discussion is about `printf()`.  MS has chosen to override the standard even in plain `printf()` — it demands the extra function call, as noted by [jxh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855519/format-modifier-and-percentage-symbol-issues#comment74747020_43855519).

Comment: Note that using `%n` at the end of a format string is unnecessary.  You could use `int k = printf("Hello\n");` to get the same information.  OTOH, in the middle of a string, it can (occasionally) be very helpful — but it is something of a security risk because people are not used to `printf()` writing on parameters.  That's why the `%n` conversion specification is not supported by the `printf_s()` function — MS and Standard C11 Annex K.

Comment: @jxh i copy pasted the source code that MSDN provides for the _set_printf_count_output() , it does not enable  the %n. It says disabled on all occasions. Maybe it is altogether forbidden in windows ?

Comment: If the `_set_printf_count_output()` function doesn't work, then you may be out of luck altogether.  That's certainly the direction Microsoft has moved in with the `printf_s()` and the warnings, etc.  But it is unusual for them to break compatibility so much that even the documented workaround doesn't work any more.  You did call `_set_printf_count_output()` with a non-zero argument, didn't you?  Did you trap the return value, and try printing it, and try calling it a second time, and printing the return value, etc?

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler yes to all. google the _set_printf_count_output() and look at MSDN sample code they provide. That is what i tested.

Comment: If your code blocks environment is using MinGW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199572/code-blocks-mingw-and-the-n-conversion-character